# Fragment onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onclick, fragment

My onListItemClick is never call when i click on item, the class is extends fragment not listfragment, because i have other view items in this fragment which is not list, so how to implement onlistitemclick in class extends fragment?

class

```
public class MainFiles extends Fragment 
{
    ArrayList<String> items;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.files, container, false);

        Button button_up = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_up);
        items = new ArrayList<String>();

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, items);
        ListView myList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly add the `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

You must also make sure that your `Fragment` implements the `OnItemClickListener` type:

```
public class MainFiles extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener
```

---

Another way is to create a dedicated subclass of `OnItemClickListener` to pass to the `ListView`:

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new MyOnItemClickListener());

/* ... */

private class MyOnItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    /* ... */

}
```

Comment: No! You don't have to implement that interface please! I've beens seen this conceptual error for a while. A Fragment has nothing to do with a OnItemClickListener so It's conceptually wrong to see it that way. The correct approach would be to create a OnItemClickListener in place. I'll highly recomend to learn more about what and when to implement an interface, It's a fundamental concept in OOP.

Comment: @FabricioPH Something like this? Note the answer is almost two years old, and the OP hinted he wanted to do it the first way.

Comment: @NiekHaarman yes, that's better. But besides how he wanted to do it, it's conceptually wrong, not well OOP. Your first solution will certainly work but it's not right to let people who is starting to learn OOP use it that way because it's conceptually wrong. The class MainFiles shouldn't be seen as an OnItemClickListener, that's my claim.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to set the setOnItemClickListener

after `myList.setAdapter(adapter);` add this:

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id){
        new File(items.get(position));
        fileList(path.get(position));
        showPath(current_path);                 
    }
});
```

Comment: I have post the same answer, ty anyway i will +1 to it :)

Answer (score 2):

I have implement listener in fragment like this

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        // list view
        listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setListAdapter(new DetailsAdapter(getActivity(), list));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // handle click here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment has to extend ListFragment, you can have more things in your layout other than a list if your layout has a listview with id=android:id/list